# Honda Activa purchased 2 days back.. morning faced starting issue

Tags: starting, scooter

Purchased honda activa before 2 days in andhra pradesh, 1 day after faced starting problem. and after applying choke it started. My worry is is the bike having any problem? was dealer delivered repaired bike to me? or is it general issue which will happen to any other very new bikes also? Honda executive at the time of delivery told me that please start bike after applying choke, so engine life will be good. Is that true? after facing starting issue, i'm doubting honda executive words. Can you also, explain me what are the check should be taken place while buying new bike in andhra pradesh? It is really appreciate if you provide answers to my queries. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to the site, Shaik.  Your question is a little unclear.  What problem are you having?  For some engines it is normal for the choke to be required when starting.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I just brought my very new honda activa from showroom 2 days back. Yesterday, in the morning, bike was not started with electric start. After applying choke only, it started. I need to know that is this a problem as it is very new bike ? or this is will happen for new bikes also?

Comment: i know that choke is required when bike is not started in normal mode. But, i'm having very new bike just 2 days old. first day it was started with electric start without choke. second day, it did not start with electric start alone. I applied choke and then pressed electric start, then bike was started. As i'm  using very brand new bike, my concern is choke required to pull for brand new bikes also? or is this really bike engine problem?

Comment: Like @JPhi1618 said, there are many factors which cause the issue. If you heard any clicking noise when press the electric starter it may due to the problem with the starter motor. Also, make sure you engage the brake lever while using the electric start and the brake lights are ON.

Answer (score 2):

If an engine has a manual choke it will need to be used for starting in most cases.  You *might* get it to start with no choke sometimes, but needing to use it doesn't indicate a problem.

Factors such as temperature, how long since it was last started, and even humidity can affect starting.  After a while you will get to know when your bike needs the choke and when it doesn't, but never hesitate to use it.